# Как настроить фильтрацию в django-filter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Не подскажите что мне делать. Умнея есть модель но я не могу её настроить каждый раз когда я её запускаю то у меня выдоёт ошибку. Что это значит и как это повиксить?
Error:

```
    raise FieldError(
        raise FieldLookupError(model_field, lookup_expr) from e
    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted.
    django_filters.exceptions.FieldLookupError: Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for field 'Realtys.Flats.Citys'.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

model:

```
class Citys(models.Model):
    City = models.CharField('Населёный пункт', max_length=200, db_index=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.City

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Населёный пункт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Населёные пункты'

class Flats(models.Model):
    Citys = models.ForeignKey(Citys, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Flat = models.CharField('Ктанегория', max_length=200, db_index=True)
    Method = models.CharField('Способ приобретения', max_length=200, db_index=True)
    Addres = models.CharField( 'Адрес', max_length=200)
    Characteristics = models.TextField('Характеристика')
    informa = models.CharField( 'Краткая информация', max_length=200)
    Area = models.DecimalField('Площадь', max_digits = 9,  decimal_places= 2)
    Area_kitchen = models.DecimalField('Площадь кухни', max_digits = 9,  decimal_places= 2)
    Room_Number = models.IntegerField('Количество комнат')
    Price = models.DecimalField('Цена', max_digits = 9,  decimal_places= 2)
    Floor = models.IntegerField('Этаж')
    imgFlat = FilerImageField(null=True, blank=True, related_name="Flats_imgFla", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    imgFlats = FilerFolderField(null=True, blank=True, related_name="Flats_imgFl", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.Flat
```

filters:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Flats, Houses, Plots


class FlatsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Flats
        fields = {'Citys': ['icontains'], 
                  'Flat': ['icontains'], 
                  'Method': ['icontains']
                  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Realtys.Flats.Citys` - это связь через PrimaryKey. Это не текст, а число.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. И извините за тупой вопрос